# How to improve RSSI on ESP32 BLE device

Tags: esp32, bluetooth-low-energy

I'm testing an **ESP Wroom 32** as BLE device (*BLE server*) using Arduino IDE and  this setup:

```
/*
    Based on Neil Kolban example for IDF: https://github.com/nkolban/esp32-snippets/blob/master/cpp_utils/tests/BLE%20Tests/SampleServer.cpp
    Ported to Arduino ESP32 by Evandro Copercini
    updates by chegewara
*/

#include <BLEDevice.h>
#include <BLEUtils.h>
#include <BLEServer.h>

// See the following for generating UUIDs:
// https://www.uuidgenerator.net/

#define SERVICE_UUID        "4fafc201-1fb5-459e-8fcc-c5c9c331914b"
#define CHARACTERISTIC_UUID "beb5483e-36e1-4688-b7f5-ea07361b26a8"

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Starting BLE work!");

  BLEDevice::init("Long name works now");
  BLEServer *pServer = BLEDevice::createServer();
  BLEService *pService = pServer->createService(SERVICE_UUID);
  BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic = pService->createCharacteristic(
                                         CHARACTERISTIC_UUID,
                                         BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ |
                                         BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE
                                       );

  pCharacteristic->setValue("Hello World says Neil");
  pService->start();
  // BLEAdvertising *pAdvertising = pServer->getAdvertising();  // this still is working for backward compatibility
  BLEAdvertising *pAdvertising = BLEDevice::getAdvertising();
  pAdvertising->addServiceUUID(SERVICE_UUID);
  pAdvertising->setScanResponse(true);
  pAdvertising->setMinPreferred(0x06);  // functions that help with iPhone connections issue
  pAdvertising->setMinPreferred(0x12);
  BLEDevice::startAdvertising();
  Serial.println("Characteristic defined! Now you can read it in your phone!");
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  delay(2000);
}
```

[image]

Very close to the ESP32 ( *20-30 cm*) the signal strenght - RSSI value is about -55 -60 dBm that is good.
Already at 2 meters (*without any obstacle*) the signal strenght drop to -70 - 75 dBm (*that is accettable*).
But at more than 4-5 meters the signal goes at - 90 dBm that is too low signal.
Is there any way to improve this behaviour?
Any idea?

P.S. You can retrieve the datasheet from this link:
[ESP Wroom 32 datasheet](https://www.bing.com/ck/a?!&&p=7d904f5c7bae3b7b92b7423edb8909110d5dc2d0ead8c005bba4e7e5d5764c2fJmltdHM9MTY1NDA5OTM2MSZpZ3VpZD1jNzI4MDU5YS05Yjg2LTQ3YzctYTRiOS0yNDY1YmVmYzIwZmQmaW5zaWQ9NTE4Mw&ptn=3&fclid=4424decd-e1c4-11ec-bf2f-1f74c6054c0f&u=a1aHR0cHM6Ly9jZG4tc2hvcC5hZGFmcnVpdC5jb20vcHJvZHVjdC1maWxlcy8zMzIwLzMzMjBfbW9kdWxlX2RhdGFzaGVldC5wZGY&ntb=1)

**Update:**
Thanks to the various reply (*especially thanks to rdtsc*)
I've solved the issue simply removing the ESP32 from the breadboard.

Now I've about 80 dBm at 5 meters between the server an the client with door closed.

It seems to me that even removing the USB calble and powering the ESP32 board with external power supply improve the things.

Thanks to all.

[image]
[image]

Comment: [BLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_Low_Energy) claims <100m range for 10-500mW transmit power.  I bet yours is 10mW, and the full 500mW is needed for full range (in ideal conditions, with perfect antennas, and zero interference.)  Please [edit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/621931/edit) your question and provide more details about the particular BLE devices, with datasheets if possible.

Comment: @rdtsc Hi. I've just updated my question with your requests.

Comment: Thanks.  Try relocating the module so that the top (the antenna) is sticking as far off the solderless breadboard as possible.  There are four long strips of metal inside the breadboard (the red and blue power rails) which could be affecting performance.

Comment: Have you tried changing the orientation of the board? Antennas do not usually radiate equally in all directions. Not sure what the radiation pattern is for those PCB traces.

Comment: Note that free space path loss adds 20 dB loss every time the distance is multiplied by 10. So the first few figures are quite normal. The next one may be due to not being in the same direction relative to the antenna, to multi path, to the orientation of the receiving device, to obstacles in the Fresnel zone… make the same measurement with a different BLE beacon, you’ll probably see similar results (and a LOT of variation).

Comment: @rdtsc Hi. Now it work much better. See the post update. The only doubt I've left is where is the ESP32's antenna. I think it is on the top of the PCB in a rectangular thin black box (but I'm not shure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image was annotated to illustrate the power rails inside the breadboard, and the antenna is circled in yellow.

[image: ESP Wroom32]

Depending on what type of antenna that is, it can be designed with a wide range of radiation patterns.  Some are also far more directional than others; if you can see a part number on that antenna or in the ESP Wroom32 schematics, it may be possible to find it's datasheet and see a chart of the actual 3D radiation pattern.  That datasheet might also give guidelines for how to use it, such as above a ground plane or in free space.

But in general, other metallic items should be kept as far away from an antenna as possible, because this usually degrades performance.  Especially for a transmitting antenna - the nearby red and blue power rails were likely "absorbing" some/most of the RF energy.

In RF, most of the "common-sense" electronics semantics go right out the window.  Those red/blue power rails could have been acting like capacitors, having the effect of being an additional load to the antenna.